# IOException: Permission Denied

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to write a file to the external storage of the android.
On the AndroidManifest.xml I've added (within the manifest tag)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

then I tried:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(root, xmlFilename);
file.createNewFile();
```

And then I get the exception.
How may I resolve this?

Comment: Can you add error logs to your question.

Comment: Which exception have you received? and what is the value of xmlFilename, it must be string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your SD card is not mounted to your computer. If you have enabled USB storage, your SD card becomes read-only for Android.

[image]

Other then that, your application looks fine and should work.

---

Oh, and I would modify your code in a next way:

```
if(root.canWrite()){
    File file = new File(root, "file.xml");         
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: silly me, it was mounted. didn't know it has that affect. anyway, now the file.creatNewFile() fails. and thank you for the modification!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the permissions set in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can also just replace "root" with your call to get the directory rather than declaring it.  What is the value of xmlFilename?

Comment: I did set the permission. String xmlFilename = "my.xml";

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the correct permissions to write to the file. In your manifest file, include this line

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />.
```

Comment: I have set it, as I wrote in the initial post. Thanks anyway :(