# how to copy database from SD Card to //database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, copy

I'm sorry for a rather green question, but I could not find solution yet.

I am trying to restore a database from a back up on SD Card. The following code (a slight modified version of one provided here in SO)

```
try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String currentDBPath =
            "\\data\\com.dg\\databases\\" + com.dg.Constants.db_Table;
        String backupDBPath = "com.dg";
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel dst = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel src = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
        line4.setText("Successful Import");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    line4.setText(e.toString());
}
```

Throws NonWriteableChannelException even though the database file is not open.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is GENERALLY in

/data/data/com.dg/databases

You need to get rid of the double \ in the path.

Also, you're using Environment.getDataDirectory() as the parent directory, then "\data\com.dg\databases\"(etc) as the file name.  That's totally wrong.

The easy way to go might be 'getDatabasePath' in Context (or Activity).  Give it the name of your DB and it should give you a File reference to it.  However, I don't know what it would do if that File didn't exist yet.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)

You may also try simple 'getDir("databases", MODE_PRIVATE)'.  That would hopefully return the database dir.

Final try for the database dir, really dirty:

```
File dbDir = new File(getFilesDir().getParentFile(), "databases");
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The directories are definitely OK- I was able to make the back up with nearly identical code in the first place.  (String "\\" appears as \ in the final output)

Comment: If you can't read/write the file, they're not OK.  You're on a unix system, so the backslashes are wrong.  They might work in some cases, but that would only be because Java is compensating for your mistake.  Seriously.  On Linux, forward slashes.  Now, the File object in java, the form you're using, takes two params.  A directory that is your parent directory, and a filename. You're passing a directory (the wrong one) and a poorly formatted directory as a filename. Try new File("/data/data/[your package]/databases/[your db file]"). That form takes a full path as a string.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. However, the problem persists. Copying to any other location on that directory (i.e. /data/data/com.dg/databases/fakeDB) is successful, but not the DB file itself. This takes place before the DB is opened for the first time (splash activity)

Answer (score 0):

Does your user / app have permissions to //database? (If not, then **THIS IS THE ANSWER**.)

Perhaps this might tell you why permission is denied:

[IOException: Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076573/ioexception-permission-denied)

[Bill Mote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617044/bill-mote) (from the above link) also pointed out the following permission setting:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: My user is not root and I have not declared any permissions (except for write external storage), though I could not find any special "database access" permission. Do you know which permission should I declare? The DB works fine, except for the copy thingy

Comment: See the above answer. If the SD was already mounted, it becomes "read-only" to Android.

Comment: The coded provided is compulsory for making the back up, but not recovering the DB from it. I am having problems replacing the file on the internal memory with the version from the SD card